# How do you erase the partition TABLE of a drive?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, partition-table

New(ish) to Linux, not new to hardware.

Got a new NAS which is to be hosted via linux. Before that I'm faffing about with the hardware, and things I will never get to do otherwise. Live distros are so lovely. I've tried around 4 so far.

Anyway, I'm also playing around with the storage drives. There's a bunch of file systems and partition types to explore - swap partitions are a puzzling idea to me, but whatever.

I can play around with those easy enough. However I could not find a way to actually delete the partition **TABLE**, just change it. I tried both `fdisk` and `gparted`.

How do you delete the partition table?

Comment: Try `dd`. Here's a similar question https://superuser.com/questions/1152069/in-linux-how-do-you-delete-the-partition-table-from-a-disk

Comment: Beware, that link only zeroes block 0, the legacy MBR. You may need to also zero the [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), starting at block 1.

Comment: [`wipefs`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/wipefs.8.html)

Comment: `fdisk` has the `m` command to get help. you should see `d delete a partition` ... that's how you can delete partitions ... or even `g` to create an empty GPT table, or `o` to create an empty DOS (mbr?) partition table - after any of those, `w` to write the new partition table and exit

Comment: `wipefs` would be the correct tool here. It even helpfully said what it did - erasing the protective MBR and GPT at the start and the secondary GPT header at the end. @meuh yea, that's a good point, but also you skipped the secondary GPT, which `wipefs` did not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do erasing a partition table.
As you said in your question, erasing a partition table is generally for using an other instead (change, but not delete).

You cannot *remove* a partition table: you can just change it, or completely clean your drive.

Here is an example using `parted`, just in case:

```bash
$ parted /dev/sdx
(parted) mklabel gpt
```

The other case is generally for removing data on the disk. For this purpose, you have a lot of simple tools to do that securely.

Here is an example using `scrub`, a Red Hat utility:

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-removing_data_securely_using_scrub

If you want more informations about erasing disks securely, I would recommend to have a look at the [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Securely_wipe_disk). There is a complete documentation about that, with performance comparison.

Just for give you some tools you could use (I'm sure there are many others):

- `dd`
- GNU `shred` *
- `scrub` *
- `wipe`
- `badblocks`
- `cat`
- `xz`

** Made especially for that, with the highest level of security (several passes, random data, etc.)*

Comment: It's a learning experience. As I said, I'm newish to linux and starting from some fundamentals. `dd` is obviously something to get intimately familiar with.

Comment: Yes, no worries, Linux has a lot of tools for drives management, so it could be a bit hard at begining !